# Functional equation for $L$-function

Tags: analytic-number-theory

I have a question: I always saw the functional equation for a $L(s,\chi)$-function, and every time it is specified that the character $ \chi \bmod q $ is primitive. In my understanding the problem is that in the proof (that I saw) is that we used the fact that $$ \chi(n) = \frac{G(\overline{\chi},n)}{G(\overline{\chi},1)} $$ where $G(\chi,n)$ is the Gauss sum. This is equivalent to saying that the character is primitive.

**My question**: is it possible to derive a similar functional equation if $\chi$ is not primitive?

Let $ \chi $ be a primitive Dirichlet character of modulo $q>1$ and $ k \in \{0,1\} $ defined such that $ \chi(-1) = (-1)^k$, denote with $ G(\chi,n)$ the Gauss sum. Then the functional equation is
$$ \Lambda(s,\chi) = \frac{G(\chi,1) }{i^k \sqrt{q}} \Lambda(1-s,\overline{\chi}) $$
Where $ \Lambda(s,\chi)$ is the completed $L$-function, defined as
$$ \Lambda(s,\chi) = \left( \frac{q}{\pi}  \right)^{\frac{s+k}{2}} \Gamma \left( \frac{s+k}{2}  \right)L(s,\chi) $$

Comment: If $\chi$ is not primitive then $\chi(n) = \psi(n) 1_{\gcd(n,r)=1}$ with $\psi$ primitive so that $L(s,\chi)= L(s,\psi)\prod_{p| r} (1-\psi(p) p^{-s})$

Comment: If you want a functional equation of the kind you describe, you need to use *all* the Euler factors. Working with an imprimitive character has the possible effect of removing finitely Euler factors from the $L$-function, and what that does in the functional equation is move those factors to the other side. You can't make them totally disappear in the functional equation itself.  If $ab = c$ and I only want to have $a$ appear on the left side, then we have $a = c/b$. You can't make $b$ disappear entirely.

Comment: If you view this whole topic from the perspective of Tate's thesis, the concept of "primitive character" completely disappears: all the different versions of a Dirichlet character (its primitive form and everything you get by lifting that to a larger modulus) should really be considered as the *same* character on a single group (the idele class group of $\mathbf Q$) that has all the groups $(\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z)^\times$ occurring as quotient groups of it.

Comment: Thank you KCd for your answer i will esplorate it! For reuns, thank you but i already knew it that relation.